# Hidden Column on ListView - Android

Tags: android, listview

I have several columns from a Database I need to show on a ListView.  I also have the ID of the record, but would like to hide that column.

Is there a way to create columns in the XML for the ListView and maybe hide it there?

UPDATE:

I tried the suggestion from the link in answer 1.  This is the code I cam up with but it dumps on the last line.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
 package com.mvw;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

 public class test extends ListActivity {

SimpleAdapter mSchedule;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  setContentView(R.layout.test);


    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("train", "101");
    map.put("from", "6:30 AM");
    map.put("to", "7:40 AM");
    mylist.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("train", "103(x)");
    map.put("from", "6:35 AM");
    map.put("to", "7:45 AM");
    mylist.add(map);


    mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});

    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);  <--- DUMPS HERE


}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to "hide" the _ID value? It should be in your `Cursor` -- you don't need to expose it to your `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: I do have it in the cursor, but how do I reference the click that has only text, back the cursor?

Comment: Your mSchedule  is not declared what it is so it is dumping there.

Comment: And I don't know what it is. tried declaring it as listAdapter and SimpleAdapter. It does not work :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial about making Multi-Column ListViews that may be helpful: http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/